# Preventing location changes even when angular is reloaded

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working on a website where part of the navigation is not handled by angular but by some entity on the server. So for instance, if I open part A of the website the server loads angular and if I use angular routing here everything is fine. I can also listen for '$locationChangeStart' events and execute functions as a result. However, as soon as I click on a link for part B of the website, the server takes control and angular is completely reloaded for the context of part B.

Ignoring the fact that the general circumstances are suboptimal (and I can't change them without substantial amounts of time, which I don't have), I'm wondering if there is a way to still catch the location change. I'd be very happy if I could use angular resources for that. Is this even possible?

For example, is there some way to execute a function when angular is destroyed (I'm assuming that something like this is happening)?

Comment: Does this mean localStorage is also reseted?

Comment: Hard to help without more routing specifics, angular and others

Comment: @charlietfl What specifics where you thinking of? Angular version is 1.3.15. We're using ngRoute of the same version. The routing between context A and B is completely handled by the server. Within those contexts we use ngRoute when necessary. Does that help?

Comment: @BrunoHenrique Well, the modules are reloaded. I'm not sure if localStorage would help but I'll think about it. Otherwise, I'll probably have to use a global function or something.